# How to attach more the role to same user?

Tags: roles, laravel-6

I can add only  one role using :

```
$user->attachRole($request->role_id);
```

But I need to make role accept being admin and up-loader in the same time for example.

*This is User controller*

```
public function store(UserRequest $request)
 {
     $request->merge(['password'=>bcrypt($request->password)]);
     $user = User::create($request->all());
     $role_id=$request->input('role_id');   //added by me
     $user->attachRoles(['admin', $request->role_id]);
    //  $user->attachPermissions($request->permissions);
     session()->flash('success','Data added successfully');
     return redirect()->route('dashboard.users.index');

 }  //end of store
```

result is ONLY ONE ROLE APPERARS

Comment: can you post your html form

Comment: Do you have `dashboard` prefix wrapped around your resource route ?

Comment: It was more the top of the form, a 404 is because it cant find the route you have set.  So would be good to see how you have set the form tag

Comment: Roue:               Route::prefix('dashboard')
->name('dashboard.')
->middleware(['auth','role:Super_admin|admin'])
->group(function(){

//make route dashboard.welcome
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index')->name('welcome');
//make route categories:
Route::resource('categories','CategoryController')->except(['show']);
Route::resource('roles','RoleController')->except(['show']);
Route::resource('users','UserController')->except(['show']);
});

Comment: <form action="{{route('dashboard.users.store')}}"  method="POST">
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="role">Role</label>
                <select name="role_id" class="form-control select2 custom-select" multiple>
                <option>Choose a role</option>
                @foreach($roles as $role)
                <option value="{{$role->id}}">{{$role->name}}</option>
                @endforeach
                </select>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus">Add </button></form>